# matching all characters in any order in regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm a regex newbie, but I understand how to match any characters in a regex query in order (ex. [abc] will match any of a, b or c.  Also, I believe "abc" will match abc exactly).

However, how do I construct a regex query that will match all the characters abc in any order?  So for example, I want it to match "cab" or "bracket".  I'm using Python as my scripting language (not sure if this matters or not).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python, I wouldn't use a regualar expression for this purpose, but rather a set:

```
>>> chars = set("abc")
>>> chars.issubset("bracket")
True
>>> chars.issubset("fish")
False
>>> chars.issubset("bad")
False
```

Regular expressions are useful, but there are situations where different tools are more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The reason why I wanted to use regex is because I'm trying to do multiple types of matches on a string: match beginning; match end; match both beginning and end; exactly match a substring.  I'm using regex for those queries, but I guess from your response "match all characters in any order" isn't something that regex isn't good at, so I'll need to separate that query out.

Comment: Elegant and compact at the same time. I wonder why I still use Java :)

Answer (score 12):

This *can* be done with lookahead assertions:

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)
```

matches if your string contains at least one occurrence of `a`, `b` and `c`.

But as you can see, that's not really what regexes are good at.

I would have done:

```
if all(char in mystr for char in "abc"):
    # do something
```

Checking for speed:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='chars.issubset("bracket");chars.issubset("notinhere")',
... setup='chars=set("abc")')
1.3560583674019995
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='all(char in "bracket" for char in s);all(char in "notinhere" for char in s)', 
... setup='s="abc"')
1.4581878714681409
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='r.match("bracket"); r.match("notinhere")', 
... setup='import re; r=re.compile("(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)")')
1.0582279123082117
```

Hey, look, the regex wins! This even holds true for longer search strings:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='chars.issubset("bracketed");chars.issubset("notinhere")', 
... setup='chars=set("abcde")')
1.4316702294817105
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='all(char in "bracketed" for char in s);all(char in "notinhere" for char in s)', 
... setup='s="abcde"')
1.6696223364866682
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='r.match("bracketed"); r.match("notinhere")', 
... setup='import re; r=re.compile("(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?:.*e)")')
1.1809254199004044
```

Comment: ...but Sven's solution most probably is more efficient.

Comment: I've got no idea which is more efficient, and both seem quite readable.  Anyway, the main purpose of my answer is to make some progress in my secret quest of obtaining the "regex" badge without ever using a single regex. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: That's a worthy and noble goal. I've done it the other way around :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Intrigued, I've done some testing. I wouldn't have guessed it, but the regex was fastest.

Comment: I'm surprised indeed.  Interesting find!

Comment: Thanks for this!  If the efficiency of set affects me then I will also look into using this as well!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a timeit comparison of [issubset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123131/matching-all-characters-in-any-order-in-regex/8123173#8123173) versus the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123131/matching-all-characters-in-any-order-in-regex/8123199#8123199) solutions.

```
import re

def using_lookahead(text):
    pat=re.compile(r'^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)')
    return pat.search(text)

def using_set(text):
    chars=set('abc')
    return chars.issubset(text)
```

---

For small strings, `issubset` may be slightly faster:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' "test.using_set('bracket')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.63 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' "test.using_lookahead('bracket')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.87 usec per loop
```

For long strings, regex is clearly faster:

- when the match comes late:

  ```
  % python -mtimeit -s'import test' "test.using_set('o'*1000+'bracket')"
  10000 loops, best of 3: 49.7 usec per loop
  % python -mtimeit -s'import test' "test.using_lookahead('o'*1000+'bracket')"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 6.66 usec per loop
  ```
- when the match comes early:

  ```
  % python -mtimeit -s'import test' "test.using_set('bracket'+'o'*1000)"
  10000 loops, best of 3: 50 usec per loop
  % python -mtimeit -s'import test' "test.using_lookahead('bracket'+'o'*1000)"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 usec per loop
  ```

---

(To answer a question in the comments:) `r'^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)'` can be used to signal a match:

```
In [40]: pat=re.compile(r'^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)')

In [41]: pat.search('bracket')
Out[41]: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x9f9a6b0>
```

Comment: It returns an empty string in that match. Anyways, if one wants to just assert if all the characters are present in the input, I guess that is fine. But if one wants to get the matched text i guess it would not help.

Comment: The matched text is the entire string. There is no need for the regex to return it. Anyway, `issubset` only returns a bool, so to make it an even comparison, the regex should not do any different.