# Efficient unordered substring matching

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, python-2.5

I want to match if one string is contained in another, regardless the order of characters. 
For example, if I have a string **submarine** I want to be able to detect **marines** as a match.

The way I'm currently handling this is through lists:

```
def match(x, y):
    x, y = list(x), list(y)
    for i in x:
        try:
            y.remove(i)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True
```

But this is inefficient when I try to match many combinations.

I thought then to use regex, but didn't make it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah right, `r'\b[submarine]+\b'`. Thanks

Comment: Sure you mean *"regardless the order of characters"*? E.g. do you also want "submarines" to match stuff like "eibsun", "inusb", "seurainb"?

Comment: If you are trying to determine if Marines is a potential anagram of submarine, this works if you don't care about letter count: `set('marines').issubset('submarine')`. If you care about letter count, `collections.Counter('submarine').subtract('marines')`, then check for negative quantity.

Comment: @IceArdor: I checked that already and that does not work here since all the chars from the set must be present in the input string. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123131/matching-all-characters-in-any-order-in-regex) is the answer for that kind of problem.

Comment: @IceArdor: `Counter` is not present in python 2.5

Comment: @vedar If you don't care about letter count: `all([x in "submarines" for x in "marines"])`

Comment: @vedar backported recipes for Counter are available in Python 2.5. Almost as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a *character class* `[SEARCH_WORD]` where each character will be searched for independently. By setting the `+` quantifier after it, you will look for 1 or more characters, and by adding `\b` word boundaries, you will only match whole words:

```
r'\b[submarine]+\b'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW7lO7/1) and the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/XNoTbC):

```
import re
s = "I have a string submarine I want to be able to detect marines as a match"
kw = "submarine"
r  = re.compile(r"\b[{0}]+\b".format(kw))
print(r.findall(s))
```

**NOTE:** If your input can contain non-word characters, especially characters like `^`, `]`, `\` or `-`, escape those with `re.escape` and use `r"(?<!\w)[{0}]+(?!\w)".format(re.escape("submarine"))`.

```
import re
s = "I have a string ^submarine I want to be able to detect ^marines as a match"
kw = "^submarine"
r  = re.compile(r"(?<!\w)[{0}]+(?!\w)".format(re.escape(kw)))
print(r.findall(s))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/pvdGBw)

Comment: just to mention that this is slightly slower that my list approach

Comment: Which one? Anyway, the list approach does not check for a whole word.

Comment: I do dictionary lookup comparison. However this is the answer I wanted so thanks again.

Comment: done. regex approach is twice faster then my list matching when using compiled pattern :)