# Python String Search Regardless Of Character Sequence

Tags: python

I want to create an application that checks if word that the user typed in contains word/words from a separate text file (e.g. input = 'teeth', separate file contains the word 'eet') it should return True regardless of the sequence of the characters.

I looked at this thread [matching all characters in any order in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123131/matching-all-characters-in-any-order-in-regex) which is cool as it's working using set(). Problem is, set() doesn't allow you to use repeated characters(e.g. eeet, aaat).

I would like to know how should I approach this problem?

Comment: then count the leters occurrences with `collections.Counter` and compare dicts.

Comment: Does input 'teeth' contain the word 'eh'?

Comment: @StefanPochmann If the word 'eh' is listed in the separate file, it should return as True regardless of the sequence of the characters. That's how I like the program to work.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a `collections.Counter` object from both strings, counting the characters, then substract the dicts, test if resulting dict is empty (which means string contains substring with cardinality respected)

import collections

```
def contains(substring, string):
    c1 = collections.Counter(string)
    c2 = collections.Counter(substring)
    return not(c2-c1)

print(contains("eeh","teeth"))
print(contains("eeh","teth"))
```

result:

```
True
False
```

Note that your example isn't representative as

```
>>> "eet" in "teeth"
True
```

that's why I changed it.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: This is clever! Originally I thought it would have to reduce to something like the classic map-reduce interview question about counting anagrams (here it would be anagrams of every substring of the input string!) -- but since the only problem is set membership, your clever idea is much better.

Comment: thanks, and your answer is another improvement for performance.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's unlikely, but if performance really mattered for very large inputs, you could avoid needing to create the second `Counter` and just iterate directly over the characters of the substring, allowing the possibility of terminating early if you run out of a given character.

```
In [26]: def contains2(string, substring):
    ...:     c = Counter(string)
    ...:     for char in substring:
    ...:         if c[char] > 0:
    ...:             c[char] -= 1
    ...:         else:
    ...:             return False
    ...:     return True
    ...: 

In [27]: contains2("teeth", "eeh")
Out[27]: True

In [28]: contains2("teeth", "ehe")
Out[28]: True

In [29]: contains2("teth", "ehe")
Out[29]: False

In [30]: contains2("teth", "eeh")
Out[30]: False

In [31]: def contains(string, substring):
    ...:     c1 = collections.Counter(string)
    ...:     c2 = collections.Counter(substring)
    ...:     return not(c2-c1)
    ...: 

In [32]: contains("teth", "ehe")
Out[32]: False

In [33]: contains("teeth", "ehe")
Out[33]: True

In [34]: contains("teeth", "eeh")
Out[34]: True

In [35]: %timeit contains("teeth", "eeh")
19.6 µs ± 94.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [36]: %timeit contains2("teeth", "eeh")
9.59 µs ± 29.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [37]: %timeit contains("friday is a good day", "ss a")
22.9 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit contains2("friday is a good day", "ss a")
9.52 µs ± 10.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Apologies for the follow up question. I would like to know how's the approach for this if the subtring is a list? I tried looping on each word in the list first then loop on each character for each word. Should i put the function inside the for loop so each loop, the value for substring will change then I will proceed with the operation?